# What would the perfomance and cost of storing every get request made into a "views" table?

Tags: performance, postgresql, database-design, heroku, server

I'm thinking about tracking page views for dynamic pages on my website for pages like the url below:

example.com/things/12456

I'm currently using Ruby on Rails with postgresql, on Heroku.

If I store EVERY get request into a table, every time a user views it, the database could grow extremely large, very quickly. Ideally, I'd like to track the time stamp, user id and user role of each request as well, so each view would have to be a row in the table, as opposed to having a "count" column for each resource.
I'd also like to make aggregate queries on this large table, for things like, total count per resource over a time period.

In terms of performance and cost, would this make sense to do? Are there better alternatives out there? 
EDIT: Let's say I have a 1000 views a day, with each user viewing 10 pages each. And I'm making 500 aggregate requests/day.
Would this be expensive or non-scalable?

(I'd also need to store POST, PUT and DELETE requests as well, into an actions table, which fits into this very same problem)

Comment: Everything has a cost. What do you mean by _extremely large_? How many queries would be done each day? I guess only the site managers would do them.

Comment: Thanks, for answering, I'll edit my post to be more specific about the cost. I was wondering what the cost of having a large database (in size) + doing all these queries against it would be, or if there are better alternatives to this approach.

Comment: You mean there would be 10,000 inserts each day? Or 7 per second. That is something but not that much. 500 queries each day is about 21 per hour. Easy. Notice that performance questions need infinitely more detail to have any chance of a reasonable answer. I'm voting this as too broad.

Comment: Over an extended period of time, there would be millions of rows in the table. I'm not looking for a specific price as answer, but a rough estimate.

Comment: We do over 200 million (pretty complex) transactions per day on a small 12-core machine with a nice FusionIO-card. It all depends on your queries and your (virtual) hardware.

Comment: From a DBA's perspective, if you run 10k inserts per day, you're talking about 3.6 million rows per year. You shouldn't have to worry about table size for at least 50 years, and *that's* assuming that technology doesn't improve. As for what "500 aggregate requests/day" means here, nobody knows. That phrase is vague enough to be essentially content-free.